# How to find dynamic width of every div with a specific name

Tags: loops, html, width

I'd like to look through my code, and everywhere there is a class of ".inner" the width will adjust accordingly to that specific ".inner" class.

Right now, the code is detecting the first ".inner" and establishing that width for all future ".inner" divs.

I believe you have to use $(this) here.. but not sure where. Right now I'm using  .each()

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="iacq_main-css" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img class="hrimage left" src="hr-image.png">
        <h2 class="wordwidth">The Story</h2>
        <img class="hrimage right" src="hr-image.png">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img class="hrimage left" src="hr-image.png">
        <h2 class="wordwidth">wejrthwkrsfsafsdfeht</h2>
        <img class="hrimage right" src="hr-image.png">
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

$('.inner').each(function(){

var width = ('.inner .wordwidth');
var widthtotal = $(width).width() + 640;

$(this).css("width", widthtotal+"px");
});


</script>

</html>
```